# Need to uninstall crashed Exchange 2013 server before installing new Exchange 2019

Tags: exchange-2013, adsi, exchange-2019

We have an old server that has suffered numerous hardware and software problems over the years. We want to simply get rid of the old Exchange 2013 server and start fresh with a new Windows 2019 + Exchange 2019 installation.

As a precaution I tried to uninstall Exchange 2013 from the old server but the box is too messed up. Uninstall fails.

What's the best approach? Do I need to go into ADSI edit and start cleaning up AD for the old server? Or just remove the old server from the domain and create a new Exchange 2019 server?  I've read mixed advice about the need to remove the software, risk of cleaning up AD which may prevent new server from installing, etc. See [this detailed walk through](https://www.pelegit.co.il/uninstall-exchange-2013-manually-force/)

(I have exported mail at the client level - so there is nothing I need to save).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ADSIEdit (or Active Directory Sites and Services, it's a bit simpler, just enable the "Show Services Node" option) and remove the Exchange main container, which is `Services -> Microsoft Exchange`; also delete `Microsoft Exchange Autodiscover` in the same place.

Using Active Directory Users and Computers, delete the `Microsoft Exchange System Objects` OU and the `Microsoft Exchange Security Groups` OU. Also delete the computer account for the failed Exchange server(s).

For additional cleanup, set all `msExch*` attributes for all your users and groups to `null`; clean also `ProxyAddresses`, `MailNickName` and `Mail`. You can use AD PowerShell to bulk cleanup all of this.

After cleaning up everything, you'll be able to start fresh by running setup /PrepareAD from the Exchange install media and then by installing your first new Exchange server.

Comment: I tried the linked answer above before I saw this one.  But I'll ASSUME it works, and accept

Answer (score 0):

The supported method is to reinstall the old Exchange 2013 server using the "Setup.exe /Mode:RecoverServer" command first and then remove it via Add/Remove Programs.
Since the Exchange settings are stored in the active directory,you can reinstall it on a new hardware with the same server name.
Here is the document for your reference: [Recover Exchange servers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/high-availability/disaster-recovery/recover-exchange-servers?view=exchserver-2019)

Using ADSIEdit may be more efficient but it is not officially supported.

Comment: This assumes the Exchange 2013 server can be restored onto the domain.  But in case you have already upgraded the domain functional level the Exch2013 server may no longer start.  (Domain incompatability)